# Average Steps Taken

Tags: python

My program runs but it only outputs "MONTH | AVERAGE". I need it to post how many steps are taken in each month.

```
days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
firstIndex = 0
lastIndex = 0

inputFile = open(r'C\Users\UserName\Downloads\steps.txt', 'r')
outputFile = open(r'C\Users\UserName\Downloads\stepsbymonth.txt', 'w')

outputFile.write('MONTH | AVERAGE\n')
print('MONTH | AVERAGE\n')
lines = inputFile.readlines()
lines = list(map(int,lines))

for x in range(0, 12):
    lastIndex = firstIndex + days[x]
    monthLines = lines[firstIndex:lastIndex]
    average = float(sum(monthLines)) / max(len(monthLines),1)
    outputFile.write(months[x] + '|' + '{0:.1f}'.format(average)+ '\n')
    firstIndex = lastIndex

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: This Python isn't very idiomatic. You might want to look at context managers as a starting point for file I/O. Also, you didn't ask a question.

Comment: you already computed the number,  just write it out `sum(monthLines)`

Comment: When I added sum(monthLines) it said that monthLines was not defined

Answer (score 0):

You're not `print`ing the number.

Also, use `outputFile = open(r'C\Users\UserName\Downloads\stepsbymonth.txt', 'a'` as you don't want to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

### I don't know if this would be considered an improvement. I've only been doing python in school for three weeks now but this is how I approached the assignment

```
# Global Variables/Constants
month = ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
         'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
days = (31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)
# Main Module
def main():
    # This calls the welcome module
    welcome()
    # This calls the Step Tracker module
    stepTracker()
# Welcome Module
def welcome():
    print ('Here is your workout information for the year:')
    print ('__________________________________________________________________')
    print ('')
# Counter Module
def stepTracker():
    # This opens the steps.txt file
    stepCounter = open('steps.txt', 'r')
    # This sets the month count to zero which begins the tuple.
    monthCount = 0
    # This loops through the months until the 12th month is reached
    for num in range(1, 13):
        # This resets the base values for the counters on each months iteration
        totalSteps = 0
        count = 0
        average = 0
        # This iterates until the end of the month is reached
        for count in range(1, days[monthCount] + 1):
            # This reads the lines until the end of the month is reached
            steps = int(stepCounter.readline())
            # This sums the months
            totalSteps = totalSteps + steps
        # This averages the steps for the month
        average = totalSteps / days[monthCount]
        # This prints the average for the month
        print ('The average steps taken for the month of ' + month[monthCount] +
               ' is: ' + format(average, ',.1f') + ' steps.')
        # This increments the months count
        monthCount = monthCount + 1
# This calls the main module
main()
```